# Oculus Go file association with intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, oculusgo

I want all files of my type (.xxx) to be open with my application on an Oculus Go.

For that I have tried a lot of things in my AndroidManifest.xml file. For now, I have all these intent filters in the main activity :

```xml
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xxx" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xxx" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-compressed" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-zip-compressed" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="multipart/x-zip" />
      </intent-filter>
```

The 4 intent filters with a mime type are for zip files. It's because my file type is ".zip" file renamed to ".xxx".

I have downloaded a .xxx file with the oculus browser and then click on it on the right panel. Nothing happened ...
I also tried with a zip file. Nothing happened ...

Is it possible to do a file association on Oculus Go ?
Am I doing something wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR No, this is not supported yet.

Oculus Browser doesn't launch intents for downloaded items. It does open video files; it handles video files as a special case.

Comment: Sorry to bother you on here, but since you seem to know about the topic and I haven't been able to get any information elsewhere: Is there an ETA for this feature, or is it something that is unlikely to be available to developers anytime soon on Oculus platforms like Go/Quest?

Comment: Sorry I don't have anything on that.

Comment: One year and a half after the original post, is there some news about file association on oculus ?